# ValueError: shapes (3,4) and (5,2) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network

i'm getting an error while running this code
ValueError: shapes (3,4) and (5,2) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
X = [[1, 2, 3, 2.5],
     [2.0, 5.0, -1.0, 2.0],
     [-1.5, 2.7, 3.3, -0.8]]
class Layer_Dense:
    def __init__(self,n_inputs, n_neurons):
        self.weights = 0.10 * np.random.randn(n_inputs, n_neurons )
        self.biases = np.zeros((1, n_neurons))
    def forward(self, inputs):
        self.output = np.dot(inputs, self.weights) + self.biases
        
layer1 = Layer_Dense(4,5)
layer1 = Layer_Dense(5,2)

layer1.forward(X)
print(layer1.output)
```

Comment: What exactly do you intend for `layer1 = Layer_Dense(4,5)` and then immediately `layer1 = Layer_Dense(5,2)` to do? `layer1` cannot be two different things at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have a mistake in the bottom, you wrote

```
layer1 = Layer_Dense(4,5)
layer1 = Layer_Dense(5,2)
```

but you should have written

```
layer1 = Layer_Dense(4,5)
layer2 = Layer_Dense(5,2)
```

Then, I think your shapes are not aligned because the first number in your `layer1 = Layer_Dense(4,5)` which is 4, is referred to your `inputs` meaning it can display as many inputs as the X has, which is 4 in one array.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

X = [[1, 2, 3, 2.5],
 [2.0, 5.0, -1.0, 2.0],
 [-1.5, 2.7, 3.3, -0.8]]


 class Layer_Dense:
   def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_neurons):
    self.weights = 0.10 * np.random.randn(n_inputs, n_neurons)
    self.biases = np.zeros((1, n_neurons))

   def forward(self, inputs):
    self.output = np.dot(inputs, self.weights) + self.biases


layer1 = Layer_Dense(4, 5)
layer2 = Layer_Dense(3, 4)

layer1.forward(X)
print(layer1.output)
```

if this doesn't help, then try changing places of a variable with inputs as a parameter, like `self.output = np.dot(inputs, self.weights)` and make it `self.output = np.dot(self.weights, inputs)` or change  `self.weights = 0.10 * np.random.randn(n_inputs, n_neurons)` to  `self.weights = 0.10 * np.random.randn(n_neurons, n_inputs)` or `def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_neurons)` to `def __init__(self, n_neurons n_inputs)`. Also don't forget to change the parameters of the layer you are printing. That made `layer1` working, but not `layer2` for some reason...

2 DAYS LATER... I noticed that my code could print `layer1`, but when I wanted to  `print(layer2.output)`,  it would say error(shape). My mistake was that i was printing the inputs in layer one, and then the same inputs in layer 2! So I had to forward `inputs` with `layer1` and then forward this `layer1.output` into `layer2`'s inputs, and print that as `layer2.output` like this :

```
layer1 = Layer_Dense(4, 6)
layer2 = Layer_Dense(6, 7)

layer1.forward(X)
print(layer1.output)

layer2.forward(layer1.output)
print(layer2.output)
```

Remember, the first parameter of `layer1` is from `X` inputs, and teh second parameter is how many neurons this layer will have, which is how many you like, so i put 6 here. The first parameter of `layer2` is from `layer1.outputs` which is in my case 6, and the second parameter is again how many neurons this layer will have, which is how many you like, so i put here 7. That way, I'm more sure your code will work and you can move to the activation function tutorial :D